# Is there a cloudscribe Getting Started Guide?

Tags: cloudscribe

I'm trying to test if cloudscribe is appropriate for a project I am starting and I'm having challenges getting a cloudscribe instance running.
I'm new to .NET Core 2 and not quite sure how to make it work.
I loaded the VSIX template into VisualStudio 2017, started a new project and got the initial configuration dialogs, but when the project is created, it's getting errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   NU1102  Unable to find package cloudscribe.Core.IdentityServerIntegration with version (>= 2.0.0-preview20170927)
  - Found 20 version(s) in nuget.org [ Nearest version: 2.0.0-preview20170828 ]
  - Found 0 version(s) in Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages  cloudscribe c:\My Documents\Visual Studio 2017\Projects\cloudscribe\cloudscribe\cloudscribe.csproj  1
```

I really would like a robust identity & authentication, so I though the IdentityServer 4(fork) option was the way to go.

If I don't select Identity Server (and using NoDB), the project launches, but the login of admin@admin / admin doesn't work...likely because the database isn't populated.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

There was a missing package on nuget that was causing that error. Sorry for the inconvenience. It should be fine now. To make usre you have the latest nuget packages, open a command window in the root of the solution and run the command:

```
dotnet restore --no-cache
```